# replace strings with another string between two $ signs

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, awk, sed

I have a file which has content like this.

```
hello , welcome
name is $foo$
bye bye
```

and I want to replace `$foo$` with `bar` like this.

```
hello , welcome
name is bar
bye bye
```

As shown, I also want to remove the surrounding dollar signs..

I have been trying something like this:

```
sed -i 's/$.*$/$foo$/g’
```

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Why did you tag this with `awk` and `sed`? Are you required to use these? Edit your question to include this information.

Comment: edited the question

Comment: Thanks for adding your attempt using `sed` -- what was the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replace everything between `$` and the next occurrence of `$` after that with `bar`, you'd do:

```bsh
sed 's/\$[^$]*\$/bar/g' < file
```

`$` is a special regex operator that matches at the end of the subject. To match a literal `$` character, you'd want `\$` or `[$]` instead¹.

To replace `$token$`s explicitly:

```bsh
sed '
  s/\$foo\$/bar/g
  s/\$abc\$/xyz/g
' < file
```

For large lists, you may prefer resorting to `perl` and do things like:

```bsh
perl -p -e '
  BEGIN {
    %map = qw(
      $foo$ bar
      $abc$ xyz
      $xyz$ abc
    );
    $regexp = join "|", map {qr{\Q$_\E}} keys %map;
  }
  s/$regexp/$map{$&}/g' < file
```

---

<sup>¹ Strictly speaking with basic regexps (the default regexps for `sed`; some implementation way switch to different flavour with some `-E`, `-r`, `-R`, `-P`, `-X`, `-A`...), `$` is only special when at the end of the pattern or before a `\)` (and possibly more for those that support extensions in their BRE). So above, you'd only need to escape the last `$`. Still, escaping when not necessary doesn't harm and easier than having to remember the special corner  cases.</sup>

Comment: i have to match foo with bar also. there can be anything , like  foo=bar or xyz=abc